# import module failed with running by console

Tags: python

First of all the project structure looks like this

```
-- ba-amin-code (main directory)
   -- Diverse
      -- LanguageIdentification.py
   -- TextAlignment
      -- FileHandler.py
      -- TextHandler.py
```

I want to import a python file from TextAlignment when im in Diverse.

[Project Structure, import statements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Fpvu.jpg)

This is how I imported it, but im getting this error when running it like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JAXA.jpg)

Is this way wrong to import?

Update:
This is how im importing two py files from TextAlignment. 
Im in `LanguageIdentification.py`

```
import fasttext
import urllib
import typer
from TextAlignment import TextHandler
from TextAlignment import FileHandler
```

After that im running the program`from the root-directory (ba-amin-code) by console with this command 
`python Diverse/LanguageIdentification.py "INPUT.txt"`

getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Snur\Pycharm Projects\Gitlab\ba-amin-code\Diverse\LanguageIdentification.py", line 4, in <module>
    from TextAlignment import TextHandler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TextAlignment'
```

Comment: Please post your directory structure and code in textual form, not screenshots. And make sure you include the relevant `.py` files, too.

Comment: Your code and error messages are still screenshots. Please replace them with text blocks.

Comment: ok I replaced it now

Comment: Try using the solutions in the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder

Answer (score 0):

The package might be installed in a different venv. Did you try running your code from the pycharm console, with your venv activated?

You have two yellow warnings in pycharm at your imports: what are they?

Otherwise, try the command: $pip list to see if the package is correctly installed in your venv.